# Whats the easyiest way to store Logstash logs from php

Tags: php, logging, elasticsearch, logstash

Im starting to use logstash for logging, because it works great with elasticsearch.

But i cant find way to easy store logs in php.

What would be fastest way to store logs from php?

File, tcp, udp others?

So i can just add one class to my application and just run one line of code, for example

```
$logclass->log('my_event', 'mymessage');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can curl from Php to elasticsearch in 2 ways:

- with Php curl extension, this will be synchronous
- with **shell_exec("curl .... &")**, this will be asynchronous but could create zombies

You can add logstash in the middle if really you have awsome traffic:

- Php --> redis --> logstash --> elasticsearch
- Php --> UDP --> logstash --> elasticsearch

Php **error_log** is also a great method, very easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

The word "easy" depends on a lot of things in this case.

- How are your logs stored?
- Are your logs already transferred over a network?
- Are your logs consolidated in 1 file?
- What is your knowledge of rsyslog or other system logging systems?

It would be best if you just tried something out and then came back with a more concrete question.
Each option has pros and cons...for example, UDP packets are fire and forget, meaning packets may get lost. TCP packets may block up your network if too many are dropped. Files need local storage space to store the file so that the file can be read into logstash.

Do some research and try something out, but I don't think I'm able to give you a proper answer only based on the information you have provided.

Also, `$logclass->log('my_event', 'mymessage');` has nothing to do with whether you choose TCP, UDP of File.